# How to add file with extending prototype in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript1.8

Suppose i want to extend String.prototype, so i have this in ext/string.ts for example:

```
interface String {
    contains(sub: string): boolean;
}

String.prototype.contains = function (sub:string):boolean {
    if (sub === "") {
        return false;
    }
    return (this.indexOf(sub) !== -1);
};
```

When i do `import * as string from 'ext/string.ts'` it fails with this error:

> error TS2306: File 'ext/string.ts' is not a module

and this is supposed behavior , i didn't write export.
But how do i tell to Typescript that i want to extend String.prototype then?

Comment: Honestly, you should really consider not extending the built-in types like this. When some future ES version comes out with its own native implementation of `contains` your code will override that and possibly be slower than the native code. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/215552.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just need to run the file without importing anything. You can do that with this code:

```
import "./ext/string";
```

---

However, if your `string.ts` file contains any import statements then you will need to take out the interface and put it in a definition file (`.d.ts`). You need to do this with external modules so that the compiler knows it needs to be merged with the `String` interface in the global scope. For example:

```
// customTypings/string.d.ts
interface String {
    contains(sub: string): boolean;
}

// ext/string.ts
String.prototype.contains = function(sub:string): boolean {
    if (sub === "") {
        return false;
    }
    return (this.indexOf(sub) !== -1);
};

// main.ts
import "./ext/string";

"some string".contains("t"); // true
```